# Sumifs in Pandas with two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want the pandas equivalent of the Excel's `sumifs` for example

```
=SUMIFS($D4:D$107,$D$107,$G4:G$107)
```

I have three columns, the `contract`, the `amount` and `transaction_type_tla`. For each `contract`, I would like to sum the `amount` if the transaction type is `CBP`. The following formula is not working:

```
data['Var']=(data.groupby('contract',"transaction_type_tla=='CBP'")['amount'].cumsum())
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I think @Wen's answer is more in line with what you're looking for, but in case you wanted the result as a series:

An easy way to do this is to first filter the list of transactions by the transaction_type_tla you're looking for and then apply the groupby and whatever aggregation method you want:

```
ans = data[data['transaction_type_tla'] == 'CBP']
ans.groupby('contract')['amount'].cumsum()
```

This will result in a series with your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Borrow jp'data :-)

```
df['New']=df.groupby('contract').apply(lambda x : x['amount'][x['type']=='CBP'].cumsum()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df
Out[258]: 
  contract  amount type    New
0        A     123  ABC    NaN
1        A     341  ABC    NaN
2        A     652  CBP  652.0
3        A     150  CBP  802.0
4        B     562  DEF    NaN
5        B     674  ABC    NaN
6        B     562  CBP  562.0
7        B     147  CBP  709.0
```

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012981/create-excel-like-sumifs-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

This is one way. I've set up some imaginary data to test.

Output is dataframe in same format, but with `CBP` transactions summed.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 123, 'ABC'],
                   ['A', 341, 'ABC'],
                   ['A', 652, 'CBP'],
                   ['A', 150, 'CBP'],
                   ['B', 562, 'DEF'],
                   ['B', 674, 'ABC'],
                   ['B', 562, 'CBP'],
                   ['B', 147, 'CBP']],
                  columns=['contract', 'amount', 'type'])

s = df.groupby(['contract', 'type'])['amount'].sum()
df = df.set_index(['contract', 'type']).join(s, rsuffix='_group')

df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'CBP'], 'amount'] = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'CBP'], 'amount_group']
df = df.drop('amount_group', 1).reset_index().drop_duplicates()

#   contract type  amount
# 0        A  ABC     123
# 1        A  ABC     341
# 2        A  CBP     802
# 4        B  ABC     674
# 5        B  CBP     709
# 7        B  DEF     562
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'A':['RAFAEL','RAFAEL','GIOVANNA','GIOVANNA','GIOVANNA','GUSTAVO','BRENNO','BRENNO'],'B': [100,3000,500,10,5500,600,700,1000]})

#sumif

for i in range(len(test)):
    test.loc[i,'C'] = test[ test['A']==test.loc[i,'A' ]]['B'].sum()

#sumifs

for i in range(len(test)):
    test.loc[i,'C'] = test[ (first)&(second) ]['B'].sum()

test
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Can you [edit] your answer to add some description on how that answers the question.