# Pandas: How to SUMIF similar to excel

Tags: python, excel

I have a data set with 400,000+ data points and I need to do a SUMIF statement I can write the function in excel without it crashing for a small subset but I want to be able to do it with pandas the excel formula is pretty simple:

```
=SUMIF(K$3:K$10000,"<"&K3,I$3:I$10000)/SUM(I$3:I$10000)*100
```

I wrote a code that works, but is very slow (~4hours) to do the entire dataset. I feel like there is a faster method. The excel function aligns with the for loop at the end.

Python Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
                
#Initialize Variables
#Import file
df = pd.read_csv('export_dataframe.csv')
df['Rank'] = df['% Grain'].iloc[:].rank(ascending=0,method='max', na_option = 'bottom')
df['Mass'] = df['Rank'].iloc[:]/np.count_nonzero(df['Rank'].iloc[:])*100
Total_Cu = df['Cumulative Grain'].sum()
df['Cumulative Grain'] = 0
for i in range(len(df['Rank'])):
            df['Cumulative Grain'].iloc[i]=df.loc[df['Rank']<df['Rank'].iloc[i],'Cu % Grade'].sum()/df['Cu % Grade'].sum()*100
```

edit:
I looked at the answer to another question and it was similar however it relied on the condition to be constant, in my case each item in the list will have a different condition based on the value in that specific cell. It may just be that I don't know how to use lambda properly. This is what I tried to do to fix it, but it doesn't work.

```
df['Cummulative Cu'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Cu % Grade'] if x['Rank'] < x['Rank'].iloc[:] else 0, axis=1)
df.matches.sum()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Excel-like SUMIFS in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012981/create-excel-like-sumifs-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not exactly sure what is in 'export_dataframe.csv' and so am not sure exactly what columns are in your dataframe. I was able to wrap your for loop in a list comprehension though and I think it does what you need, much much quicker. You reference `df['Cu % Grade']` in the loop, but I didn't see it in your earlier code, so sorry if the code doesn't reference the exact column you need. I'm sure you can edit it a bit to suit.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit

# make a DF
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cu % Grade': np.linspace(0,1,10000)})
df['Rank'] = df['Cu % Grade'].rank(ascending=0,method='max', na_option = 'bottom')
df['Cummulative Cu'] = [(df.loc[df['Rank'] < df.loc[i, 'Rank'], 'Cu % Grade'].sum()/ df['Cu % Grade'].sum())*100 for i in range(len(df))]
```

So with 10k rows I get...

```
s = '''
df['Cummulative Cu'] = [(df.loc[df['Rank'] < df.loc[i, 'Rank'], 'Cu % Grade'].sum()/ df['Cu % Grade'].sum())*100 for i in range(len(df))]
'''

%timeit s
14.7 ns ± 0.241 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

A quick tip: if you find yourself HAVING to use a for loop, often it is much quicker to wrap it in a list comprehension. You can read up on list comprehensions here: [list comprehensions in python](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

Comment: Happy to help! Your question got me over 50 reputation and now I can comment, so thanks to you too :)